# Can MaaS Cluster Controller be on a VM

Tags: maas

I have limited number of servers and since it is a small setup it would be a waste to have a server dedicated to the cluster controller.

I was wondering if it can be installed on a VM on my laptop so whenever I make changes I just turn it on and use it.

If that is possible could the cluster controller be moved to a physical server later when the environment gets larger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert here, but I don't see a reason not to do this, as long as the VM gets a static IP. By having all the data on the VM, you actually gain an advantage by having the ability to move the VM to a more powerful machine if you need to, to without having to worry about migration the configuration DB or files.

With that being said, I am not sure how to actually migrate the VM's data to a physical server without having to redefine the cluster again.

Tip: The controller should not use much CPU, but In case you are using juju and you see the controller get bogged down due to "nonce already used" do this workaround: https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1190986

Comment: I tried a test environment with cluster controller on a VM on my laptop. It worked fine but I immediately realized two issues. First cluster controller provides DHCP and DNS so having it on my laptop and taking it away from the network is out of the question due to DNS issues arising after a while. Second even if setup the DNS on the router side and have a VPN tunnel all the time between my laptop and the network. Destroying Juju services and deploying new ones take forever because it is pushing the image over the VPN. The only solution would be to do a VM on a server in the same network.

Comment: We have a setup in which we use a separate DHCP server to serve 3 maas environments. That probably doesn't help you much because, yeah, I think that the images need to be served by the controller

Comment: I will mark this as answered because technically it should be possible but it's too much of a hassle. I even tried putting KVM on one of the servers. However having cluster controller and bootstrap on the same node causes the network to go down on the KVM.